# $ \frac{\mathbb{Z}_{2}[X]}{(X^{3}+X+1)}$ is isomorphic to ...?

Tags: abstract-algebra

> $P= X^{3}+X+1$. I have to find for each element (except 0) of $ \frac{\mathbb{Z}_{2}[X]}{(P)}$ the inverse element for the multiplication. I maybe thought that $ \frac{\mathbb{Z}_{2}[X]}{(P)}$ was isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{8}$, is that correct? If not, can someone give a hint to make an isomorphism? Thanks

Comment: I'm curious if this actually standard notation somwhere? In the US, I never see ring modulo ideals written as $\frac{R}{I}$, but I see it somewhat commonly on this site.

Comment: Well, $\mathbb Z_2$ is a field, and $P$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Z_2$, thus $\mathbb Z_2[X]/(P)\cong \mathbb Z_2[\alpha]$ for a root $\alpha$ of $P$. This is a field extension, and thus, most definitely not $\mathbb Z_8$.

Comment: But we didn't see yet , the thing about irreducible. I just thought $\mathbb{Z}_{8}$ consists of 8 elements, but that seems wrong...

Comment: Well, you are right about $8$ elements, but $\mathbb Z_8$ is not even integral domain, let alone field. Well, this isomorphism is easy enough to establish, take evaluation $\mathbb Z_2[X] \to \mathbb Z_2[\alpha]$. It's kernel is $(P)$, thus the isomorhpism follows from First isomorphism theorem. Now, since $P$ is of degree $3$, can you see that any element of $\mathbb Z_2[\alpha]$ is of the form $a+b\alpha + c\alpha^2$? Try to work with that.

Answer (score 2):

Any polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}_2[X]/(P)$ is equivalent to $a+bX+cX^2$ for some $a,b,c\in \mathbb{Z}_2$ since $X^3 = X+1$ ($-1=1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2$). Take the polynomial $X$, then consider all of its powers and calculate them
$$
\color{red}{X},\: \color{red}{X^2},\: \color{red}{X^3}=X+1,\: \color{red}{X^4} = X^2+X, \:\color{red}{X^5}=X^2+X+1
, \:\color{red}{X^6} = X^2 + 1, \: \color{red}{X^7}=1$$
As you can see every element of $\mathbb{Z}_2[X]/(P)$ is generated as a power of $X$ except for $0$. Now from the above it is clear what element is the inverse of what element since $X^7=1$. $X(X^2+1) = 1$, $X^2(X^2+X+1)=1$ and $(X+1)(X^2+X)=1$.